# Paypal subscription cancelled after completing current cycle

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

```
function change_subscription_status( $profile_id, $action ) {

    $api_username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $api_password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $api_signature = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    $api_request = 'USER=' . urlencode( $api_username )
                .  '&PWD=' . urlencode( $api_password )
                .  '&SIGNATURE=' . urlencode( $api_signature )
                .  '&VERSION=76.0'
                .  '&METHOD=ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus'
                .  '&PROFILEID=' . urlencode( $profile_id )
                .  '&ACTION=' . urlencode( $action )
                .  '&NOTE=' . urlencode( 'Profile cancelled at store' );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp' ); // For live transactions, change to 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp'
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );

    // Uncomment these to turn off server and peer verification
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE );
    //curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );

    // Set the API parameters for this transaction
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $api_request );

    // Request response from PayPal
    $response = curl_exec( $ch );

    // If no response was received from PayPal there is no point parsing the response
    if( ! $response )
        die( 'Calling PayPal to change_subscription_status failed: ' . curl_error( $ch ) . '(' . curl_errno( $ch ) . ')' );

    curl_close( $ch );

    // An associative array is more usable than a parameter string
    parse_str( $response, $parsed_response );

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($parsed_response);
    echo "</pre>";

    //return $parsed_response;

}

change_subscription_status( 'I-ASLDBP8A3W1T', 'Cancel' );
```

This code cancel subscription immediately, but I want to stop subscription after completing current cycle of subscription.

Comment: You simply can't. A subscription that's cancelled has no bearing on the end date of the subscription. You should be handling this logic in the other part of your application where you're checking to see if a subscription is valid.